# docker doesn't see heroku environment variables

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku

I have django/react/postgres/docker app. When I try to push it to heroku it doesn't see environment variables from heroku config vars tab during build phase

---

#### Is there a way to get heroku environment variables inside of the docker container?

---

On heroku I attached Heroku Postgres addon, but since my env variables are hidden during build phase I'm getting an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting                                                           
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

##### Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /app/backend

COPY ./backend/Pipfile* /app/backend/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY ./frontend/package*.json /app/frontend/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /app/frontend/build

RUN mkdir root && find . -type f -exec cp {} root \;

RUN mkdir /app/backend/staticfiles

WORKDIR /app

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.prod

RUN python backend/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

EXPOSE $PORT

RUN ["python", "backend/manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]
CMD [ "python", "backend/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0", $PORT]
```

##### settings.py

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env.str("DB_NAME", default="postgres"),
        'USER': env.str("DB_USER", default="postgres"),
        'PASSWORD': env.str("DB_PASS", default="postgres"),
        'HOST': env.str("DB_HOST", default="localhost"),
        'PORT': env.decimal("DB_PORT", default=5432)
    }
}
```

#### Project structure

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── config
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── pages
│   ├── Pipfile
│   ├── Pipfile.lock
│   ├── templates
│   ├── todos
│   └── users
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile.prod
├── frontend
│   ├── build
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
├── heroku.yml
└── README.md
```

Comment: You're specifying "config.settings.prod" as your config path... but is not in the image (building time). Are you mounting that file as volume (runtime) ?

Comment: I use `docker-compose.yml` only for development. I just run `git push heroku master` to deploy app. I think settings files are copied by `COPY . /app/` command in `Dockerfile.prod`

Comment: Had you tried setting config vars https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars ?

Comment: Yes, all config variables are set

Answer (score 1):

### There were two issues with my code:

- I forgot that when django settings split into dev/prod variations and placed into separate directory `settings` you must search for `.env` file inside parent directory. So in `settings/prod.py` file I changed `env.read_env()` to `env.read_env(BASE_DIR.joinpath('..', '.env'), recurse=False)`
- I removed `python manage.py migrate` command from my `Dockerfile.prod` and executed command `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. I suppose I could place migration command into `heroku.yml` file